# Problema al comprobar contraseñas con PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo mi archivo PHP que obtiene los datos de una Base de datos y después los compara con los dados y si las credenciales coinciden, se redirige al usuario a una página en específico. En mi base de datos tengo varios registros, por lo que habría que buscar cuál coincide, pero no logro hacer que funcione correctamente.

La forma en que encripté la contraseña al recibirla desde el usuario, fue de la siguiente manera:

```
$hashedPassword = password_hash($password, PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

Y luego tengo que comprobarla:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

$email = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$contra = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'contra', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$host = "host";
$username = "user";
$password = "pass";
$dbname = "dbname";

//Crear la conexion SQL
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
  die("Conexión fallida: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT password FROM webcustomers WHERE email = ?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "s", $email);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $hashedPassword);
mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt);

if (password_verify($contra, $hashedPassword)) {
    // Si la contraseña ingresada es correcta, inicia sesión en la aplicación
    $hashedCookieEmail = hash("sha256", $email);
    $hashedCookiePass = hash("sha256", $hashedPassword);
    setcookie("emailUsuario", $hashedCookieEmail, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    setcookie("contraUsuario", $hashedCookiePass, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    header('Location: https://strant.store/tienda.php');
    exit();
} else {
    // Si la contraseña ingresada es incorrecta, muestra un mensaje de error
    echo "<script>
    Swal.fire({
      icon: 'error',
      title: 'Oops...',
      text: 'La contraseña es incorrecta'
    });
    </script>";
}

mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

Comment: Se me pasó, gracias!

Comment: En la variable $contra querrás decir?

Comment: No, me refiero al momento de guardar en el campo `password` de la tabla `webcustomers` lo que indico el usuario. Ya que estamos, también deberías chequear el que largo de dicho campo sea lo [suficientemente largo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/25020/16597)

Comment: Bien, en mi mail tengo juanpepito@examplemail.com y en password tengo juanpepito123.

Comment: Eso no es lo que quise decir, fíjate en el link que compartí en mi comentario anterior. Si te fijas en el código de la pregunta, vas a poder ver que se usa `password_hash` para generar la cadena que se guarda en el campo "password" de la tabla. Revisa que vos lo estes haciendo de la misma forma.

Comment: Listo, fue modificada mi pregunta. Creo que es eso a lo que te refieres.

Comment: ¿Compraste que el campo sea lo suficientemente lago para almacenar por completo el hash? Y ya que estamos, ¿podrías darme el hash guardado en la tabla para el usuario `juanpepito@examplemail.com` y contraseña `juanpepito123`?

Comment: Sí, el campo es varchar(50). El hash para juanpepito es el siguiente: $2y$10$nKtWgF4uz7JO7LEzh96g5OIEDz5VzvFvLYAS6Q03Ulf

Comment: Ahí esta el problema, si lees la documentación [`PASSWORD_BCRYPT`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) siempre devuelve una cadena de 60 caracteres. En otras palabras, el `hash` se esta guardando truncado y por eso no funciona.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, podrías escribir la respuesta en la sección de respuestas? Así damos por concluida la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partir de [este comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/583470/problema-al-comprobar-contrase%c3%b1as-con-php?noredirect=1#comment1032220_583470):

> Sí, el campo es varchar(50). [...]

Podemos concluir que lo que esta causando el problema, es que el campo `password` de la tabla `webcustomers` **no es lo suficientemente largo**.

Si revisamos la documentación, al usar el algoritmo [PASSWORD_BCRYPT](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.password-hash.php), la función `password_hash` devuelve:

> [...] El resultado siempre será un string de 60 caracteres, o false en caso de error. [...]

#### Solución:

Modificar el campo `password` a `VARCHAR(60)`